# Is there a semaphore_broadcast or semaphore_signal_all functionality available on Mac OS X or linux

Tags: c++, linux, macos, semaphore

I have a client-server model based problem in which there is one server process and multiple client processes and the client processes are in a wait state waiting for the server to signal.

When the server signals, clients do the required processing and go back to waiting
The problem is that i need a way using which I can notify all clients that come up (register for server's notification) i.e. wake up all the client processes waiting for the signal and not just one of them.

I was earlier using `mach_semaphore` to solve this problem on Mac OS X.

So my code used the `semaphore_signal_all()` API exposed by [mach_semaphore](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KernelProgramming/synchronization/synchronization.html) but I was using a call to `bootstrap_register()` to achieve this but this system call has been **deprecated** and so is no longer useful.

I tried to look for a workaround and found [here](http://lists.apple.com/archives/darwin-dev/2009/Nov/msg00061.html) that `bootstrap_check_in()` could be the way to go but on further digging found that this needs an API `bootstrap_create_service()` which also is deprecated.

So in a nutshell, the problem is I can't find any IPC mechanism (related to semaphores or otherwise) using which I can wake all client processes waiting for the signal.

Below are some code snippets which would convey the issue better:

```
SERVER.cpp

void server()
{
    signal_all_clients_using_semaphore();
    /*
     do some processing
    */
    signal_all_clients_using_semaphore();
    /* and so on */
}

CLIENT.cpp
void client()
{
    RegisterForTheNotificationFromServer(); // internally looks up for the semaphore created by the server
    while(1)
    {
        semaphore_wait(INFINTE_TIME);
        /* do some small processing */
    }
}
```

Needless to say that there are multiple instances of client and only one instance of server running.

It would be really useful if you could provide some code snippets to back your answer.Also, your answer need not be mac specific and can be for **linux** also (but not for windows as we already have `manual reset events - CreateEvent/SetEvent APIs` using which we can achieve the desired results)

Comment: REDIS or ZeroMQ pub/sub maybe?

Comment: Posix conditional variables (and mutexes) can be used across processes. So in your case take a look at the `pthread_cond` family of functions. [`pthread_cond_broadcast`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_broadcast) for example is relevant to you. Be sure to make the cond variable shareable across processes with [`pthread_condattr_setpshared`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_condattr_setpshared)

Comment: also have a look at boost interprocess.

Comment: @kaylum Thanks for the info. Was constantly approaching this via semaphores. But as soon as i migrated to pthread_* everything seemed to work fine on linux.
But when I used the same sequence of system calls on `MAC OS X` then I could broadcast the signal only to one process as when I  attach the second client to the shared memory holding the mutex and cond var and call `pthread_cond_wait()`, this call fails returning 22.